# use tableview as uitextview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

i want to develop a application like notepad app of iphone or ipod. i try my level best to design a uitextveiw like a paper with lines but it has a lot of problems like background image does not scroll with scroll of uitextview. and does not reapeat itself when text increases the background image.

its seems to me that the notepad app use a table view for taking input from user how i donot know.

so anyone who can tell me how to design a view like notepad app.

Comment: any one we can do this. or have any alernative idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a tableview  and then place text field in each row such that if the text field limit reach the maximum length the next row text field  become first responder. and when user click save then read data from all text field and then save it where u want.

but the only problem that i am facing is when the user past some data then i am unable to show that data in next text field if the past data is larger than the maximum length of a text field.

hope this help others.

Comment: if any one seeing this page then he should also visit this one      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height/5375491#5375491