# can I show lines in the UITextView control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitextview

I want to show lines in the `UITextView` like notes application.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean, you want to display line numbers?

Comment: No you know the notes application the user can see a black lines represent the lines , I want to do something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should try and draw your lines programmatically rather than using an image.

In This Question ***Fernando Redondo*** Did something similar

[UITextView ruled line background but wrong line height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height/5453189#5453189)