# UITextView ruled line to be adjusted with the text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

to get a ruled line background with UI textview i found a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height/5453189#5453189)

i used the same code, but according to my need i have added a margin figure in the code and the figure looks as follows[image]

Now i want the text to be places next to the margin line and in the first line of every paragraph i want to show some spaces from the margin to the first word. how to do this please guide me

Answer (score 0):

When the padding view was added as subview it worked as a fine margin for me.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];    
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
textView.text = @"SomeText"; 

UIView *paddingView = [[[UIView alloc]   
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 200)] autorelease]; 
paddingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 

[textView addSubview:paddingView];   
[self.view addSubview:textView];
```