# Can anyone tell me How to draw the lines in the UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview, xcode4.3

Please any one can tell me how to add the lines in the UITextView like notes app in the iphone .
i followed some tutorials but am not able to understand..
am looking for a simple way to draw the lines in the textView..Please help me..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can subclass it an add a backgroud image in lieu of the white color.

Comment: Or you could make the UITextView transparent BG and put an image behind it.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height/5453189#5453189 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789747/uitextview-ruled-line-to-be-adjusted-with-the-text

Answer (score 2):

Simply make an background image for your textView which contain lines, and then  set it to your textView.

```
[yourTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]]];
```

Or follow this answer too [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height/5453189#5453189)

Comment: ok thanks for the advices, actually i know how to set image as a background to textView..But my problem is that how to get that type of image to set as a background image with lines to UITextView ?.     Please share the link of that kind of image if any body having ...