# UITextView Not Previewing in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, uitextview

When I open old xcode projects or add a new UITextView in Xcode 5, UITextViews are appearing empty.
It is appearing only editing. Can I see preview?

Answer (score 0):

You can give shadow or background color to textView which makes it visible.
Otherwise you can add lines to the textView.

For lines you can refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375350/uitextview-ruled-line-background-but-wrong-line-height).